# How to set numpy array value based on previous value?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Example:

```
a = np.array([1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 4])
```

Goal:

Set value to 0 if the previous value is 0

Desired output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a mask of the locations that are zero:

```
m = (a == 0)
```

Apply the mask to a shifted slice of the array:

```
a[1:][m[:-1]] = 0
```

In some cases, you may want to shift by incrementing the indices:

```
i = np.flatnonzero(m[:-1]) + 1
a[i] = 0
```